# Compute Bell numbers in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, combinatorics

This is what I already implemented:

```
function B = bell(n)
B(1,1) = 1;
for i=2:n
    B(i,1) = B(1,end);
    for j = 1:i-1
        B(i-j,j+1) = B(i-1,j)+B(i,j);
    end
end
end
```

When n=3, i got:

```
 1     2     3
 1     3     0
 2     0     0
```

instead of:

```
 1     2     5
 1     3     0
 2     0     0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your line

> `B(i-j,j+1) = B(i-1,j)+B(i,j);`

into

```
B(i-j,j+1) = B(i-j+1,j)+B(i-j,j);
```

Example: for `n=5`,

```
B =
     1     2     5    15    52
     1     3    10    37     0
     2     7    27     0     0
     5    20     0     0     0
    15     0     0     0     0
```

in accordance with [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number#Triangle_scheme_for_calculations).